# Can't install app after delete folder contain database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I using SQLite to contain data.

I deleted folder contain database include: `callrecord.db` and `callrecord.db-journal` files.

And open again app show error: Unfortunately, Record has stopped.

So I change `path` to create the new path in code, but when to run again the error again appear.

The `log cat Window` throw exception:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kr.co.composer.callrecord/kr.co.composer.callrecord.page.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

My code in create is:

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Lapsoft-CRM/callrecord.db";
public CallDatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + NAME + " varchar, "
            + PHONE_NUMBER + " varchar, "
            + START_TIME + " varchar, "
            + CALL_TIME + " varchar, "
            + SEND_RECEIVE + " varchar, "
            + PHOTO_ID + " integer, "
            + FILE_NAME + " varchar"
            +");";
    Log.i("Tạo 1 bản cơ sở dữ liệu", sql);
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String sql = "drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME + ";";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

How to fix this error? Thank you very much.

Comment: you need uninstall old app before install same app again

Answer (score 0):

The database file name (`DATABASE_NAME`) should not contain any directory.

Just use the base file name (`"callrecord.db"`); then the directory will be created automatically, if needed.